# C# Winforms Backgroundworker error - object not set to an instance of object

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I have a winforms file search application that runs with no errors in visual studio, but when i publish it i get a "object not set to an instance of object error"

The backgroundworker code which is the point where it fails is :

```
    private void backGroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Result = RunSearch();
        PopulateUi((FilteredList)e.Result);
    }

    private void backGroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
                var ans = (FilteredList)e.Result;
                toolStripStatusLabel1.Text += "Folders found: " + ans.FolderCount + " | Files found: " + ans.FileCount;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

The messagebox shows the exception text.What do i need to do to correct this?

**EDIT**
This question is different to the one referred to above as its about a concurrency issue and not simply an object being null. As stated above, the application runs with no errors before publishing.

thanks

Edit 2

I have tried creating a private object ( _x) in the class and assigning the result to it, but it still shows as null in the RunWorkerCompleted function. The edited code looks like this:

```
    private void backGroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Result = RunSearch();
        _x = e.Result;
        PopulateUi((FilteredList)e.Result);
    }

    private void backGroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (_x == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("e is null");
            }

            var ans = (FilteredList)_x;
            toolStripStatusLabel1.Text += "Folders found: " + ans.FolderCount + " | Files found: " + ans.FileCount;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: We can't do much from here, the only way to find your exception is debugging. You can run your application after publishing and open Visual Studio > Debugger > Attach to process. Remove your catch and the debugger will be able to stop right where the exception happens.

Comment: Thanks @ThadeuFernandes. I tried that and the code stops at the last line where im trying to show results on the toolstriplabel. the reason is that e.Result is null in Runworkercompleted.

Comment: You're welcome! Glad to know it worked for you.

Comment: The RunWorkerCompleted event handler is not good enough, it does not deal with the possibility that the worker failed with an exception.  No result, kaboom.  Checking e.Error is not optional.

Comment: @HansPassant thanks for the reply. I also tried with if(e.Error != null) ... but had the same result.

Comment: Well, the second snippet is not correct either, it just keeps motoring even if the x variable is null.  Do make sure to test this on your own machine, temporarily add `throw new Exception("testing");` at the start of DoWork.